# why c doesn't check for return statements at compilation

Tags: c

I have started learning c. If a function is not called why compiler doesn't catch it as an error.

```
int foo(){}
void main(){}
```

I know it is a silly thing but could not figure it out.

Comment: are these things checked at run time?

Comment: Well, probably because you don't have warnings/errors turned on in your IDE. And if you get it compiled in some way you will for sure get a runtime error

Comment: @Rizier123: No; you get undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not an error, but a good compiler will emit a warning for this, provided you have warnings enabled, e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`.

Comment: `void main()` isn't standard. Use `int main(void)` or `int main()` instead.

Comment: I am using codeblocks 13.12, and I think warnings are on, because I am getting warnings are in other programs.

Comment: @Rizier123 I feel you may be getting confused between calling an undefined function, and not calling a defined function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function isn't called, that function will be doing nothing, and won't hurt to sit there. Also, sometimes you want to make libraries of functions, and these will not be called from anything in the compiled code, but may be called from other executables or libraries. The compiler will not know anything about this at compile-time.

There's probably a warning you can switch on on your compiler though.

Answer (score 2):

You compiler doesn't know that your function isn't used, so it can't warn you about it. It's possible that in another file you declare this function and use it. The linker would then resolve it to this file after compilation.

On the other hand, if you enable warnings (e.g. by passing `-Wall` to the compiler), it will warn you of possible problems whenever possible.

For example if I compile your code with `clang -Wall yourcode.c` I get :

```
yourcode.c:1:11: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo(){}
          ^
yourcode.c:2:1: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]
void main(){}
^
yourcode.c:2:1: note: change return type to 'int'
void main(){}
^~~~
int
2 warnings generated.
```

So as you can see, the compiler will tell you if you forget a return or write a bad main, as long as you enable warnings. But with the code you posted, it can't tell you about functions that aren't used.

If you want the compiler to warn you about unused functions, you should declare those functions `static`, this will mean that those functions will only be usable in the file where they are defined. Then the compiler can tell you if you don't use it and you'll get a warning like this one :

```
yourcode.c:1:12: warning: unused function 'foo' [-Wunused-function]
static int foo(){}
```